# How JVM returns from function

Tags: java, jvm

For example x86 pushes the return address on the stack and then ( on return) pops it. How does JVM solve that issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JVM doesn't compile to assembly.

Comment: I know it. It has nothing in common.

Comment: Do you know how to read Java bytecode? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode#Example) is a very, very basic primer.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076949/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-method-invocation-and-return.html?page=2

Comment: @Jim, there is no explicite answer.

Comment: It describes how the JVM handles function calls. What exactly are you interested in? Keep in mind that JVM is a spec and it can be implemented in any language. Oracle's JVM is implemented in `C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the jump instructions `jsr`,`jsr_w` and their `ret` they behave similarly as it happens on x86, return address and parameters are pushed on the stack and the return address is retrieved from there when returning.

But it's important to note that here we are talking about *miniature subroutines*, not Java methods.

Calls to Java methods are performed with specific `invoke_*` bytecode instructions that can vary in implementation (depending on the jvm you are using) and need to handle a lot more (e.g. virtual functions resolution) than what's required for simple jump instructions.

They will still use a stack and define a new call frame for every method call but the operation of returning from a function will be handled directly by the `invoke_*` implementation, the target java method will just need to store correctly the return value on its stack frame.